# How to get distribution of three dimension from three array on python2.7

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist

I will try to specify what I say. Firstly show you the code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    np.random.seed(1977)
    x, y = np.random.random((2, 1000))
    xbins = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
    ybins = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
    counts, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(xbins, ybins))

    print counts
```

You will get a two dimension array from this code, now if I have another array

```
       z = np.random.random((2, 1000))
```

Then how to get a three dimension array of distribution from these three arrays. I tried:

```
      zbins = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
      counts, _,_,_ = np.histogramdd(x, y, z, bins=(xbins, ybins, zbins))
```

But it's no use.
What's more, the really data file is too big to use loop statement, which will cost me hours to run it over, and it will not easy for me to check.
Thanks for thinking about the question!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve here. Can you explain the context in more detail? What are the physical meaning of x, y, z in reality? And what kind of information are you trying to extract?

Comment: The random array x,y,z in the code is just for example, the array x,y,z that I should deal with are come from a 1.2M data file,  and the formal seems like 'xx = data_txt[i][0]   yy = data_txt[i][1]  zz = data_txt[i][2]' , then I get 'x = xx[i], y = yy[i], z = zz[i]' as arrays.

Comment: And the function 'counts, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(xbins, ybins))' can only deal with 2d.     (this function output an 2d array, if it doesn't clear to you, make 'x, y = np.random.random((2,     10))', then you will see.). So, I think there must be a function can deal with x,y and z just like what 'counts, _,_,' do. But I didn't find it.

Comment: Maybe I can tell like this, I have the position coordinates of 100000 points in a three-dimensional coordinate system. Now, if I divide them into 1000 grid in the three-dimensional coordinate system, I want to know there is how many points in each grid, and this should be a 3d array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the following code according to your last comment

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((1000, 3))
nbins = 10
H, [bx, by, bz]=np.histogramdd(data, bins=(nbins,nbins,nbins), 
                               range=((0,1),(0,1),(0,1)))
```

And `H` is the summary of the number of points in each grid. In your previous code, `histogramdd` was not used correctly. The input data is the first argument which should be N x 3 array in your case.

You can see the [document of histogramdd here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html).

Comment: I really want to do it, but my reputation is not high enough to vote. I'm really sorry.("Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.")

Comment: Anyone should be able to accept an answer, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Get it (^*_*^).